# Typescript isn't narrowing variable when using instanceof

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to understand why TS isn't narrowing `inst` to just `Bar` in the example below:

```
class Foo {}
class Bar { prop = "baz" }

function fn2(inst: Foo | Bar) {
    if (inst instanceof Foo) {
        inst = new Bar()
    }
    inst.prop // prop does not exist on Foo | Bar
}
```

Comment: A type gard only narrows within its scope. Outside the `if` *TS dosn't know` what `inst` was. Yes, you're changing it inside the `if` but you're not changing *its type*.

Comment: @VLAZ That's not strictly true. https://tsplay.dev/wX7MoW

Comment: @AlexWayne ooh, interesting! I've not actually encountered that case. I'm curious why it's not applied in OP's code, then. Is it because it's a parameter? EDIT: I guess not: https://tsplay.dev/wOJyMW I'm more curious now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typescript is *structural*, not *nominal*. So the problem here is that an instance of `Bar` is *assignable* to type `Foo`, so the type guard doesn't actually narrow anything.

```
class Foo {}
class Bar { prop = "baz" }

const inst: Foo = new Bar() // fine
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=4&ssc=36&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8C+AoUkYCEwCcVoAHfeY6AXmgCIAjMALxug03gDsIAXaASy7cAXHERVoHAKYB3aHnwAKAJTQA9KugAzAZKA)

An object with one property conforms to the interface of an object with no properties, since all properties (all zero of them) are accounted for.

---

To make this work, you need to make the two classes have different interfaces.

```
class Foo { foo = 'foo' }
class Bar { bar = 'bar' }

declare let inst: Foo | Bar

if (inst instanceof Foo) inst = new Bar()
inst.bar // works
inst.foo // error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG9oDNHQLzQOQfl2gF8AoUSGAITACcVoAjO7PZ2os0gEwFMLavaCF4AXaAEsAdhFEAuOJgA+0GrVKkJaaAAppsyTNFgpwXvG0J4ASkMGcU3gHdVdHdc1GAdO2gB6P2gneFoAawhPWS8Cf0DeWloQoA)

---

Or in your specific case:

```
class Foo { foo = 'foo' }
class Bar { bar = 'bar' }

function fn2(inst: Foo | Bar) {
    if (inst instanceof Foo) {
        inst = new Bar()
    }
    inst.bar
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG9oDNHQLzQOQflwF8AoUSGAITACcVoAjW7aAIiZtelJLQFcAdsAAuAS3gD0AgEwAKUQIjCAXHEwAfaNRoBKFCWiHootNHmLhxi2CEBTeKYTw9yA0fcKlLAbYDuW2lkdN0NSDwsAOg4SUiA)

Comment: Thank you!!! I knew I was going to get my mind blown on this one because I had no idea what was happening LOL.  Just went down a rabbit hole reading about structural vs nominal, and I understand now. Thanks again.